# Repetir a imagem para linhas abaixo - MACRO

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

A fórmula VBA para inserir imagens na planilha funciona, porém eu preciso repetir o mesmo código para linhas abaixo, porém a imagem é apagada da linha anterior, aparecendo apenas na linha em que acabei de inserir o código.

Por exemplo: Se eu colocar o código cachorro nas linhas 1 e 2, ele apaga a foto do cachorro de uma das linhas e a foto aparece em uma única linha. Preciso que a foto apareça em todas as linhas que tenham o código do cachorro.

Não sei se ficou claro.

Segue código:

```
Public Function getImage(ByVal sCode As String) As String

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim oImage As Shape

    Set oCell = Application.Caller ' Célula onde a função foi chamada
    Set oSheet = oCell.Parent      ' Planilha que chamou a função

    ' Procura por uma imagem existente identificada pelo código (que precisa ser único!)
    Set oImage = Nothing
    For i = 1 To oSheet.Shapes.Count
        If oSheet.Shapes(i).Name = sCode Then
            Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i


    ' Se ainda não existir uma imagem com o código, carrega do arquivo e cria-a.
    ' A imagem já é posicionada na exata posição da célula onde a função foi chamada.
    If oImage Is Nothing Then
        sFile = "c:\temp\sopt\" & sCode & ".jpg"
        Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(sFile, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, oCell.Left, oCell.Top, oCell.Width, oCell.Height)
        oImage.Name = sCode

    ' Caso contrário, se a imagem já existir, garante que ela se posiciona e cabe exatamente dentro da célula
    ' (apenas para o caso do usuário ter movido ou redimensionado manualmente a imagem sem querer)
    Else
        With oImage
            .Left = oCell.Left
            .Top = oCell.Top
            .Width = oCell.Width
            .Height = oCell.Height
        End With
    End If

    ' Retorna nada para a célula (afinal, esta é somente uma função de auxílio)
    getImage = ""

End Function
```

Comment: Olá! Tudo bem? Por favor, poderia postar o código aqui para que fique mais fácil de ter ajudar? Obrigada!

Comment: Olá Diego. Por favor não use o campo de resposta para adicionar detalhes da pergunta. Basta [edit] a pergunta. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, obrigada por retornar o meu comentário, postando o seu código!

Basicamente, o que eu fiz foi mudar a variável para capturar a imagem de "Shape" para "Picture" e, assim, usar o método Insert, que não causa o "sumiço" da imagem que estava te causando problemas.

Atente apenas a mudar, no código abaixo, o nome da aba da planilha em que as imagens serão inseridas e o caminho da pasta onde as imagens estão:

```
Public Function InserirImagem(ByVal Nome As String) As String

Dim W       As Worksheet
Dim objPic  As Picture
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim strFolder   As String
Dim strFileName As String

'Seleciona a aba e a célula ativa
Set W = Sheets("Base")
W.Select
Set rngCell = ActiveCell


'Atribui o caminho da pasta e das imagens
strFolder = "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\Stack\"
strFileName = Dir(strFolder & Nome & ".jpg", vbNormal)

'Busca a imagem
Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
objPic.Name = Nome

'Formata a imagem de acordo com o tamanho da célula
 With objPic
    
        .Left = rngCell.Left
        .Top = rngCell.Top
        .Height = rngCell.Height
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    
    End With

End Function
```

Espero que ajude!

Qualquer problema, me avise!